# Azure DNS: NXDOMAIN for existing record

Tags: azure-dns

I have created a cname record for my domain(login.auditman.sam-solutions.in) using Azure DNS. Cname record points to the azure front door.

When I'm doing DNS Lookup for the record, I can successfully get the result, but when I'm trying to open the domain on a web browser, I'm getting NXDOMAIN error.

Can anyone please help me to understand what can be the possible issue regarding this?

Comment: NXDOMAIN is cached. How long have you waited after creating the DNS resource record? Flush the DNS cache on your local system. If your home router caches, reboot it.

Comment: After creating the DNS record, I've waited for at least 72hours. I have cleared all the browsing data and restarted the browser. Also, I have rebooted the router and flushed the device DNS(using ipconfig /flushdns), but still, I'm getting NXDOMAIN error

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: login.auditman.sam-solutions.in

Comment: That URL is a CNAME to a CNAME to a CNAME to an A record. The final address 13.107.213.41 (which is probably a group of IP addresses) is offline. You last updated the Registrar today and enough time for those changes to propagate has not occurred. The Azure DNS server has the correct address, but global DNS servers, such as Google DNS, do not yet. Stop fiddling with your domain. Make the correct configuration once and then wait at least 24 hours for propagation.

Comment: There is some issue at Azure end. Only US DNS Servers like AT&T DNS & Verizon DNS are able to resolve the domain name into IP address and no Indian DNS Servers like Cloudflare DNS, Google DNS or OpenDNS are able to resolve the domain name.

Comment: The problem is with how you set up your domain on Azure DNS. Azure DNS (the service) is not the problem. For example, **sam-solutions.in** is not functioning. A subdomain must have a working parent domain.